# nightmare-download-manager in aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nightmare

I was using nightmare js to automate a file download. So two days back we decided to move this tool in to aws lambda and I Was able to get the aws stuff running with nightmare using [nightmare-lambda-tutorial](https://github.com/dimkir/nightmare-lambda-tutorial), but my lambda used one more nightmare module [nightmare-download-manager](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-download-manager) Adding this download manager, lambda fails with the `'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'` message, although I have the package installed using npm install and I do find the folder and files inside node_modules.

So with debugging, I found that even with the initial few lines of code, the lambda fails like for example,

```
var binaryPack = require('./lib/bootstrap/nightmare-lambda-pack'), 
Xvfb = require('./lib/bootstrap/xvfb'), 
Nightmare = require('nightmare');

require('nightmare-download-manager')(Nightmare);
```

Line 4 will cause the module Not found error. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you post the entire error message and stack trace where it says 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?

Comment: Looks like this is the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719236/nightmare-js-not-working

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like either:

- Your new dependency didn't get packaged into your deployable `.zip`, *or*
- Your new zip didn't upload/deploy correctly.

I don't think there is any reason for this particular package to have a problem in the Lambda environment.  I followed the [linked to tutorial](https://github.com/dimkir/nightmare-lambda-tutorial), deployed and tested the lambda, added the `nightmare-download-manager` dependency, **repackaged and redeployed**, and everything works as expected.

---

**Verify your deployment**

After verifying the dependency exists in your workspace and in your deployable zip file, if you still have issues, you'll want to verify the dependency exists in the lambda environment.

I didn't see a way to verify the existence and contents of `node_modules` in the AWS console, but you can [do so with the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html):

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name <function-name>
```

Included in the response is a link (good for 10 minutes) that will allow you to download the zip file your code was deployed from.  Download this zip, and verify that `node_modules/nightmare-download-manager` is inside it, containing the expected files.

If it is missing, something went wrong with your packaging or with the upload/deployment of your package.  Repackage (zip up `lib`, `node_modules`, and `index.js`), and redeploy using the AWS console.

Assuming it is there, the `require` statements in the question work fine for me on both Node 4.3 and Node 6.10.

Comment: -package.json
-index.js
-lib
 |
 |__ bootstrap
 | |
 | |_nightmare-lambda-pack.js
 | |_xvfb.js
 |
 |
 |__node_modules
  |
  |_nightmare
  |_nightmare-download-manager
  |_aws-sdk
  |_fs
  |_mime .                                                  I just downloaded and checked the function and the structure looks fine like the above one